# store data for bookmarklet

Tags: bookmarklet

I am making a bookmarklet, which calls a Google App Engine app. The GAE app uses login information, which I want to store in bookmarklet, so when user first clicks bookmarklet,it asks for login info, but from next time onwards it automatically supplies it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difficulty of a bookmarklet directly storing data is that it can only store data in cookie or in localStore, both of which "belong" to whatever page it is currently on. That means it won't work again the next time you use it on a different page, and it also means the page you are on can access the data, which is generally very bad for security.

There are two basic ways your situation is generally handled. The two main ways are:

1.) The application used keeps the user logged in with a cookie. The login information is not stored in the cookie; only a session ID is. This is like when you return to many popular websites, you don't have to log in again. Very often these types of bookmarklets open a small popup for the user which contains a page from the app. If the user is not logged in, the app prompts the user to login first. The bookmarklet in fact knows nothing about being signed in or not.

2.) Each bookmarklet is custom created for each person. So my bookmarklet would be different than yours. The difference is simply that mine will contain my login info in the code, and yours will contain your login information in the code. In fact we would each have to login to the app first before we can get our own personalized bookmarklet.

Generally, option 1 is better and easier and more secure.

Comment: There is a third option. You use lazy signup to create a new user in the background if the user is logged out. When the user returns to your site you have them login and claim their data, that was temporarily saved under the lazy user account. This has a pitfall that if the session times out, or cookies are cleared then the user will not be able to claim their activity - but the user doesn't have to login either...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, option 1 is the best suited for me, despite my lack of javascript knowledge.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding how method 1 works.  Say I am already logged in via another page.  How does the bookmarklet get the session ID so that it can hit the page itself? (And how come if I hit server xyz from any page, the cookies the browser knows for xyz aren't sent with that request anyway?)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand it correctly,this Might help you. http://ajaxian.com/archives/whats-in-a-windowname

It allows for storing data in windowname in JS. Allowing for access of up-to 2 MB of data (A lot more than cookies can hold) and I believe can be used across tabs...

Comment: The link is dead